# Как проверить строку на наличие подстроки по маске?

Tags: php

Есть массив строк, и нужно проверить наличие в них номера по маске, например:

> 1541585289-31

то есть 10 цифр, дефис и 2 цифры

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с регуляркой:

```
$str = "1234567891-12";
var_dump(preg_match("~\d{10}-\d{2}~", $str));
```

Comment: попробовал с такой строкой: 's 1541585289-31 s', не сработало, однако если сделать так:
preg_match('([0-9]{10}-[0-9]{2})', $string)
получилось))

Comment: @zoinx2012, не сработало, ибо я указал, что строка должна начинаться с числа и заканчиваться тоже. Если этого не надо, то можно просто указать. Сейчас обновлю ответ

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас предложат регуляркой но можно и просто

```
$parts = explode('-', $number, 2);
if(isset($parts[0]) && isset($parts[1])) {
    if(stlen($parts[0]) == 10 && strlen($parts[1]) == 2) {
         echo 'ok';
    }
}

echo 'fail';
```

Comment: тут один минус, массив строк разный, а это всего лишь строчка которую спарсить нужно, а если в строке будет контент помимо строки. то все отвалится)